# "... that(,) for that purpose, we need ..." Is comma (,) required?

Tags: commas

In my email to a university official, I used the following construction,

> In the file that you attached, it is said that, for our case, we need another document.

I understand that this sentence could've been worded better, but let's consider it as an example.

What I'm concerned about is the comma after "that".
As I understand, it is grammatically correct to surround "for our case" with commas, but if you read this sentence aloud, it might be reasonable to make a pause only after and not before "for our case".

Therefore I'd like to ask you, what about commas around "for our case"? Should they always be used in formal writing?

Comment: The problem isn't with commas, it's with the cumbersome construction. Do you mean **for our case** (legal overtones) or **in our case** (in this instance)? Are you simply trying to say: In the attached file you inform us that we need (to provide) another document?

Comment: @RonaldSole, You're right about the construction being bad, thank you for pointing this out. However, I mentioned from the start that the quote is only an example of the grammatical case. Yes, we can change it, but it's not the point of this question. I meant no legal overtones in the quote. You provided a correct rewording of the phrase, but unfortunately that doesn't answer the stated question.

Comment: The number of commata around an inserted phrase like “for our case" ought always to be even, in writing, regardless of the number of pauses in speech.  In my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information that I got through this time, the commas here are correct, although it really needs to be reworded because it needs too many commas.